# Scrolling tableview getting duplicate images

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, duplicates

Im using NYXProgressiveImageView(https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit)  to load the image into cell progressively

When I’m scrolling getting duplicate images 
How can i avoid this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Customcell"];
if (cell == nil) {


    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

  }

[cell.Imageview1 loadImageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]];//Here Imageview1 is NYXProgressiveImageView.

}
```

I think Its due to progressive download,I want to do similar to  this http://nghiatran.me/advanced-issues-the-right-way-to-load-content-in-backgrounds-thread-with-tableview/

How to do this this with NYXProgressiveImageView class

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` override `prepareForReuse` and set the `imageView.image = nil`. The cell's are reused in a table so unless you clean it out before it gets reused it will appear to "duplicate" your data.

Comment: Im setting nil in "didEndDisplayingCell" method, is it not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You might give [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) a try, it supports progressive image decoding and there are no known bugs. Check out demo project for an example on how to enable and use progressive decoding.